# Can I use a external lib that use external lib in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have an app "Square" written in react-native.
I have an external lib written by me.
I wrote the bridge inside my lib, and now I can call "methodA()" from react-native.

But, methodA() will call okhttp' s method (native java code).
Does this flux work?

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. Does both your library and library from react-native have methodA() defined?

Comment: I have methodA in java and exported following react-native instruction.